# using wp_sprintf at wordpress option page,

Tags: wp-admin, options

I'm using a custom option page to control default setting of my plugin, in one part I need to let the admin add a text which will be send through sms, I need using some predefined text (such as blogname) in this text something like :

```
wp_sprintf(__('This is the smaple sms from %s', 'my_plugin_textdomain'), esc_attr( get_option('blogname')));
```

how could I do this? Is it even possible to perform such action using wp_option, I know many plugins such as woocommerce using this kind of saving text

Comment: Why not just ask the user to use `%s` in the value as the placeholder? Then pass that to `sprintf()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it comes to user-defined strings, it's best to use a placeholder or "merge tag" - so on your settings page, inform the user they can use e.g. `{blogname}`

And then in your code:

```
$message = get_option( 'option_name' );
$message = str_replace( '{blogname}', get_bloginfo( 'name' ) );
```

This is less error prone & clearer to the user than using `sprintf` style arguments.